# TFS-2010 - Custom Work Item Control not showing up: "Form Rendering Failed: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: user-controls, customization, extensibility, workitem

I'm developing a custom control for Task/Bug Work Items so I can query for shelvesets related to the Work Item.

First off I tested a simple control with nothing but a listbox with an Item. When I preview the layout form in the Process Editor in VS2010, it shows up alright, but when I create a new Task, upon loading it shows a message instead of my control:

**"Form Rendering Failed: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**

What I really like about these error messages is that they're always crystal clear... I'm clueless, what could be causing this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Clark

~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Place the dll and .wicc of the custom control you created in:
  C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Work Item Tracking\Custom Controls\10.0
- Make sure your .wicc file directs to your dll correctly.
- Refresh the team project in the team explorer.

If your WIT control is functional it should work.

Good Luck!